# variable sized object may not be initialized

Tags: c

I am getting the error `variable sized object may not be initialized` and I don't understand why.

Could someone show me how to fix this line?

```
int arr[size] = (int *)(augs->one);
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>

int count = 0;

int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

struct structure {
    int two;
    int *one;
};

void *sort(void *augments) {
    struct structure *augs = (struct structure*)augments;

    int i = 0;
    int size = 1;
    size = augs->two;

    int arr[size] = (int *)(augs->one);
    //int *arr = (int *)data;
    //printf("sizeof:%d\n", sizeof(arr));

    qsort(arr, size, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
    printf("finaloutput:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    // number of lines in file
    char charicter;

    for (charicter = getc(myFile); charicter != EOF; charicter = getc(myFile)) {
        if (charicter == '\n') {
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("count is %d\n", count);

    int numberArray[count];
    int i = 0;

    if ((myFile = fopen("data.txt", "r"))) {
        while ((fscanf(myFile, "%d", &numberArray[i]) != EOF)) {
            ++i;
        }
        fclose(myFile);
    }

    assert(argv[1] != NULL);
    int num = atoi(argv[1]); //num equals number input
    int arrayarray[num - 1][(count / num)];
    int idx;

    for (i = 0; i < (count); i++) {
        printf("numberarray[%d]= %d\n", i, numberArray[i] /*[0],numberArray[i][1]*/);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
        for (idx = 0; idx < (count / num); idx++) {
            arrayarray[i - 1][idx] = numberArray[i * idx];
        }
    }

    ///*
    for (i = 0; i < ((count / num)); i++) {
        printf("arrayarray[0]=%d\n", arrayarray[0][i]);
    }
    //*/

    int lastarray[((count / num) + (count % num))];
    for (idx = 0; idx < ((count / num) + (count % num)); idx++) {
        lastarray[idx] = numberArray[idx + ((count / num) * (num - 1))];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ((((count / num) + (count % num)))); i++) {
        printf("lastaray[%d]=%d\n", i, lastarray[i]);
    }
    //*******************
    pthread_t thread_id_arr[num];

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        pthread_t tid;
        struct structure *augs;

        if (i != (num - 1)) {
            augs = malloc(sizeof(struct structure) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) * num);
            (*augs).one = arrayarray[i];
            (*augs).two = (count / num);

            pthread_create(&tid, NULL, sort, augs);
        } else {
            (*augs).one = lastarray;
            (*augs).two = (count / num) + (count % num);

            pthread_create(&tid, NULL, sort, augs);
            //pthread_create(&tid, NULL, sort, (void*)lastarray);
        }

        thread_id_arr[i] = tid;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread_id_arr[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your initialization of `arr[size]` doesn't make sense.  This is an array of integers, and is variable sized.  You're attempting to initialize it to a pointer.  What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Put a semicolon after the `]`.  Then set the array to known values using a loop or other executable code.  You cannot use an initializer with a VLA.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.7.9 Initialization(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p3)

Answer (score 3):

As others pointed out, you can't initialize a Variable Length Array with a pointer, like you are doing. However, you don't actually need a VLA at all. Use this instead :

```
int *arr = augs -> one;
```

You want to act directly on the array that is passed into the thread, not make a copy of it.

That being said, I see another problem. In the loop that spawns the sorting threads, you are not allocating a new `args` on the last loop iteration, it reuses the allocated `args` from the previous iteration, which can cause disaster for the 2nd-to-last thread. You need to move the `malloc()` call above the `if`.

Also, the `malloc()` is allocating more memory than your threads actually use. You only need to allocate enough memory for just the struct by itself, not for any integers following the struct.

Also, when each thread is done using the allocated `args` that it is given, it needs to `free()` the `args` to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: Further problems: `charicter` must be defined as `int`, `myFile` should be rewound instead of reopened without an intervening `fclose`, the comparison function is incorrect for large `int` values, `count` will be incorrect if the file is not formatted correctly and `fscanf()` will loop forever or have undefined behaivor... And of course the output of all threads will be mixed beyond recognition